# printing data from a database with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Everyone says printing data from a MySQL database is easy but so far I'm stumped. I am new to PHP, and am trying to print out an individuals data from a database. So for example Joe Bloggs has logged in, and then he can view what his hobbies are etc. So what I am trying to achieve is getting a user to log in and see THEIR info.

Basically, the user can log in, however I tried to set a up variable to store the SQL query and then print it out if the user logged in successfully, however I now get the following error message- that will no go away.

```
( ! ) SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for
( ! ) Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in    C:\wamp\www\myfiles\login.inc.php on line 32
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0015  365584  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   1.0144  387472  include( 'C:\wamp\www\myfiles\login.inc.php' )  ..\index.php:6
3   1.0427  390752  mysql_fetch_array ( )   ..\login.inc.php:32
```

Like virtually all beginners I have made the mistake of creating a massive file that overcomplicates what am trying to code,(it is also very late a night and I'm tired hence why I might not be able to see any errors). However it is well commented

I would appreciate any comments and suggestions!!

```
// create variables username and password,if a user doesn't enter a UN and PW send error message
if (isset($_POST['username'])&& isset ($_POST['password'])){
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    if (empty ($username)&&empty ($password)){
        echo 'supply username and password';
    }
// save  our MySQl queries as variables in order to reference them later on

    // for login
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `username`='$username'AND `password`='$password'";
    // user login result
    $result= mysql_query($query);
    // display the courses that user is taking
    $user= "SELECT * FROM `students`";

// set conditions for login 
    if($result) {
    // if the data matches by rows send a message saying the user has logged in
        if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

            $_SESSION['SURNAME_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] = $member['password'];
            session_write_close();
            //if logged on list course they are studying
            echo 'you are now logged in.<a href = "logout.inc.php">Log out</a>';
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user))
                {
                    echo $row['GivenName'],$row['username'], $row['password'],$row['Course1'],$row['Course2'], $row['Course2'];
                    echo "<br />";
                }
            exit();
        }else {
            // create boolean condition- if no match send error message
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
            session_write_close();
            echo 'invalid username/password combination';   
            exit();

            }
        }
    }else {
    // display errors
        echo mysql_errno() . ": " . mysql_error(); exit();

    }

}

?>
<form method="POST">
Username: <input type = "text" name="username"> Password: <input type ="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Variable $user contains string "select....". Mysql_fetch_array needs resource to be parameter. So try $tmp = mysql_query($user) and next while($row = mysql_fetch_array($tmp))...

Comment: If your users can have multiple courses, you might also consider storing that in a separate lookup table between your students table and a courses table. YOur lookup table would have the user id and the course id.

Answer (score 3):

Heres are some of basics step that may help you if your a beginner in using php and mysql depends on what connection you are suitable to use..

**MYSQLI** :

FIRST : SET UP CONFIGURATION FOR DATABASE USER,PASS,HOST,DBNAME

```
$conn = new mysqli('database_server','database_username','database_password','database_name');
```

SECOND : Create a Query(you may insert your query here)..

```
$result= $conn->query("SELECT SUM(Total_Steps) AS value_sum FROM users");
```

FINAL : SHOWN RECORDS USING MYSQL FUNCTIONS LIKE..

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['dabatase_columnname'];
    echo $row['database_columnname'];
}
```

**PDO** :

Connect to Database
    db = new PDO("...");

Create a Query

```
$statement = $db->prepare("select id from some_table where name = :name");
```

Execute query with the bind paramater

$statement->execute(array(':name' => "Jimbo"));

Fetch all data return by query

```
$row = $statement->fetch(); // Use fetchAll() if you want all results, or just iterate over the statement, since it implements Iterator
```

**MYSQL** :

FIRST : SET UP CONFIGURATION FOR DATABASE USER,PASS,HOST,DBNAME

```
$conn = mysql_connect('database_server','database_username','database_password');
mysql_select_db($conn,'databasename')
```

SECOND : Create a Query(you may insert your query here)..

```
$result= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(Total_Steps) AS value_sum FROM users");
```

FINAL : SHOWN RECORDS USING MYSQL FUNCTIONS LIKE..

```
while($row = $result->mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['dabatase_columnname'];
    echo $row['database_columnname'];
}
```

Comment: Start slow, and build your way up.  Kaii has given you the first step.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you didn't do this:

```
 mysql_query($user);
```

just add before the `mysql_fetch_array` like:

```
$user_result = mysql_query($user);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($user_result)){
     //...
}
```

But, yes, as another said, please use `MySqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As noted, [avoid using mysql_* functions in new code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained and are officially deprecated.

Here is an example of your code, using PDO, and prepared statements. You should probably only have to change connection information.

```
<?php
// Get your connection sorted.
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=utf8', 'username', 'password');
// Prepare a few statements for use later.
$stmtResult = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `students` WHERE `username`=?AND `password`=?");
$stmtUser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `students`");

// create variables username and password,if a user doesn't enter a UN and PW send error message
if (isset($_POST['username'])&& isset ($_POST['password'])){
    $username= $_POST['username'];
    $password= $_POST['password'];

    if (empty ($username)&&empty ($password)){
        echo 'supply username and password';
    }

    // Use the try catch paradigm instead of if/else, because PDO will
    // throw an exception if things go sideways.
    try{
        // Execute the prepared statement, passing in the variables.
        $stmtResult->execute(array($username, $password));
        // Get the results in an array & then get the result count.
        $rows = $stmtResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $row_count = $stmt->rowCount()

        if($row_count > 0) {
            session_regenerate_id();
            $member = $rows[0];

            $_SESSION['SURNAME_NAME'] = $member['username'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_ID'] = $member['password'];
            session_write_close();
            //if logged on list course they are studying
            echo 'you are now logged in.<a href = "logout.inc.php">Log out</a>';
            $stmtUser->execute();

            // I moved this next call down to the loop because
            // there is no real reason to call it sooner than this
            while($row =  $stmtResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {
                echo $row['GivenName'],$row['username'], $row['password'],$row['Course1'],$row['Course2'], $row['Course2'];
                echo "<br />";
            }
            exit();
        }else {
            // create boolean condition- if no match send error message
            $errflag = true;
            if($errflag) {
            session_write_close();
            echo 'invalid username/password combination';   
            exit();

            }
        }
    }catch(PDOException $ex) {
        // This is what happens if something did go sideways.
        echo $ex->getCode() . ": " . $ex->getMessage(); 
        exit();
    }
}

?>
<form method="POST">
Username: <input type = "text" name="username"> Password: <input type ="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Log in">
</form
```